# Data conversion using tidyverse?

Tags: r

I have a data frame like below,

```
all_long<- structure(list(site = c("DK_B", "DK_M", "HU", "IT", "NL", "UK", 
"DK_B", "DK_M", "HU", "IT", "NL", "UK", "DK_B", "DK_M", "HU", 
"IT", "NL", "UK"), group = c("NEE_D", "NEE_D", "NEE_D", "NEE_D", 
"NEE_D", "NEE_D", "NEE_D_se", "NEE_D_se", "NEE_D_se", "NEE_D_se", 
"NEE_D_se", "NEE_D_se", "NEE_W", "NEE_W", "NEE_W", "NEE_W", "NEE_W", 
"NEE_W"), y = c(21.3096546929104, 32.9239223290104, -9.76133775037159, 
-1.17370950853892, -10.950117466455, 84.8932664133039, 17.4144184458657, 
21.4374932407618, 28.7765100449838, 8.86774764999355, 42.0054504158082, 
121.363143982517, 29.8709775563496, -28.2034713980476, -62.2858574112861, 
56.3557615426375, 52.3723812566745, 2.26453931798947)), row.names = c(NA, 
18L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to convert the data frame to a new one like below,

```
site   group      y                  SE
DK_B   NEE_D  21.3096546929104     17.414418
DK_M   NEE_D  32.9239223290104     21.437493
HU     NEE_D  -9.76133775037159    28.77651
IT     NEE_D  -1.17370950853892    8.867747
NL     NEE_D  -10.950117           42.005450
UK     NEE_D  84.893266           121.363144
DK_B   NEE_W    29.9               15.3 
DK_M   NEE_W   -28.2                39.5 
HU     NEE_W   -62.3               19.2 
IT     NEE_W   56.4                25.6 



......
```

I don't know how to realize this?

Comment: What happened to the rows for site UK and NL in your expected output ;) ?

Comment: @dario Same in the UK and NL sites. I just give a brief output not include all of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible approach with `tidyverse` -

```
library(tidyverse)

all_long %>%
  mutate(col = str_extract(group, 'se'),
         col = replace_na(col, 'y'),
         group = trimws(str_remove(group, col), whitespace = '_')) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = col, values_from = y)

#  site  group      y     se
#  <chr> <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 DK_B  NEE_D  21.3   17.4 
#2 DK_M  NEE_D  32.9   21.4 
#3 HU    NEE_D  -9.76  28.8 
#4 IT    NEE_D  -1.17   8.87
#5 NL    NEE_D -11.0   42.0 
#6 UK    NEE_D  84.9  121.
```

Create a new column with `'se'` text from `group` if present or replace it with `'y'`. Clean up the `group` column to leave it with only the value `'NEE_D'` and get data in wide format.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

1.To me it looks like the simplest approach was to just bind the SE values to the existing data. So we take all the rows containing the SE data and rename the column y to SE and get rid of the no longer needed group variable and then join them to the data *without* the rows containing the SE data.

```
  library(dplyr)
  library(tidyr)
  all_long %>%
  filter(!grepl("se$", group)) %>% 
  left_join(all_long %>% filter(grepl("se$", group)) %>% rename(SE = y) %>% select(-group))
  
  Returns:
```

> ```
>     site group          y         SE
>   1 DK_B NEE_D  21.309655  17.414418
>   2 DK_M NEE_D  32.923922  21.437493
>   3   HU NEE_D  -9.761338  28.776510
>   4   IT NEE_D  -1.173710   8.867748
>   5   NL NEE_D -10.950117  42.005450
>   6   UK NEE_D  84.893266 121.363144
> ```

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. But the reality is, except for NEE_D, I also GEP_D and other parameters. How to match with various parameters?

Comment: @LEE I've updated the answer to account for the new constraint (though you already accepted the other answer which is totally fine)

Comment: Sorry, I just tested your code with various `group` parameters, it seems like I will get some wrong outputs. The NEE_D values of the same site will repeat 6 times with SE values continuously joined.

Comment: Thank you for the info... I can see how this code might fail in these cases ... However, I could only test my suggested answer with the data you provided. If the structure is different it might raise issues. Sorry if it does not work for that data. Providing a good MRE is not always easy...

Comment: My bad. I just updated my sample data.